# workaround to lost metadata when saving objects to localStorage

Tags: javascript, local-storage

**The problem**

I have a webpage where I upload data (a csv file), that data is parsed and each line is fed thru an object constructor function to product objects that populate an array.

So after I upload the file, I have an array of custom objects. There are a number of methods I call on these objects and it works fine and great and everything.

Naturally, when I close the browser, I lose that information, so I wanted to save those objects to localStorage so I don't always have to upload the file I'm working with.

But the problem is that when I save the files to localStorage, the data is preserved wonderfully, but the metadata of the objects is lost.

So if I close the browser, and open it back up, the content is retrieved from localStorage but my array with the data is now an array with a bunch of anonymous objects (with all the right data mind you).

So the problem for me is that my methods do not work anymore.

**A brief example**

```
/* defining an object constructor and method */
function ball(x, y) {
 this.x = x;
 this.y = y;
}
ball.prototype.display = function() {
 console.log('x: ' + this.x + ', y: ' + this.y);
}

/* creating an array and populating with ball objects */
var ballArr = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
 var min = 10;
 var range = 30;
 var x = Math.floor(Math.random()*range+min);
 var y = Math.floor(Math.random()*range+min);
 ballArr.push(new ball(x, y));
}

/* calling the display method on the ball objects of the ballArr array */
for (var i = 0; i < ballArr.length; i++) {
 ballArr[i].display();
}

/* saving the array to localStorage and clearing the initial array (to mimic closing the browser)*/
localStorage.ballArr = JSON.stringify(ballArr);
ballArr = [];

/*setting ballArr to the contents of its localStorage equivalent
  notice that the content of the objects are the same, but now they have no names */
ballArr = JSON.parse(localStorage.ballArr);
console.log(ballArr);

/* this bit here will cause an error: ballArr[i].display is not a function */
for (var i = 0; i < ballArr.length; i++) {
 ballArr[i].display();
}
```

**A question**

My goal is to have my webpage search localStorage first to see if there is data saved, if not, the array is blank.

The array can be populated by uploading a csv file. This action also replaces the localStorage object.

Is there a way to do this where, if no data is uploaded but localStorage contains data, my methods can still be called on the objects retrieved from localStorage?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the way you save and retrieve the data from local storage may be the issue. Try these instead:

```
localStorage.setItem('ballArr', JSON.stringify(ballArr));

if (localStorage.getItem('ballArr') !== null){
    ballArr = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('ballArr').toString());
console.log(ballArr);
}
```

Handle the case if the data is not in local storage and if it is, retrieve the data toString then parse it to JSON.

Comment: I gave this a shot but no luck.

Comment: I updated my answer to include the method to set `localStorage`. Currently you are making a reference to `ballArr` instead of setting the value of `localStorage` to the stringified `ballArr`

Comment: Still no luck. In my code, I stringify the array, send to localstorage, wipe the original array, then retrieve the string from localstorage, parse it and store it in the original array. It's meant to recreate (sort of) closing and opening the browser when it's saved to localstorage. but i think i have found another way, by saving my uploaded csv string to localstorage, and remaking the objects

Comment: All this while I thought that was exactly what you were attempting. I'm glad it worked out for you.

Answer (score 0):

Although it's possible to serialize and store the function definitions in localStorage as well, that's not ideal or recommended way to do it. Instead, after retrieving the data from localStorage you should re-create the objects using the data, as if creating them the first time, but using the values just loaded.

Comment: I'll implement this. I guess I figured I could do it this way but I didn't know if I was missing out on some of localStorage's functionality so I thot it would be worth asking. Out of curiosity, how would I do it the first way? Because that had never occurred to me.

Comment: No, don't do it the first way, it's a bad choice anyway.

Comment: *"...you should re-create the objects using the data, as if creating them the first time, but using the values just loaded."* What happens when values are changed but not uploaded to the server, then the session is over because the user logs off or closes browser? OP doesn't want to upload to server for some reason. Values loaded wouldn't be the updated version, correct.? Is there anything like code that would make your comment into an answer?

Comment: You're right that it's not going to a server. When I upload a file I use a filereader object to execute some callbacks which more or less take the csv file and turn it into an array of objects. Without using localstorage, the array is populated during that session alone only after an upload was made. And each time I upload, I wipe the array first so I start fresh. The data itself does not really change and there are only a handful of end-users. I think it will probably work for me to use the object retrieved from localstorage to feed the constructor and populate the array that way.

Comment: This worked, but it turned out to be easier to save my uploaded csv file (just a string) to localStorage. It's easier to retrieve, and I can just feed it thru the function i have which converts it to an array of custom objects.